# Load txt-file with two different delimiters into struct

Tags: matlab, file, struct, loading

I'm having trouble with loading *.txt* file in Matlab. The main problem is having not equal rows. I'll attach the file so you can more clearly see what I'm truing to say. First, the file has information about each node in graph. One row has information like this:

```
1|1|EL_1_BaDfG|4,41|5,1|6,99|8,76|9,27|13,88|14,19|15,91|19,4|21,48...
```

it means:

```
id|type|name|connected_to, weight|connected_to, weight| and so on..
```

I was trying to use `fscanf` function, but it only reads whole line as one string. How I suppose to divide it into struct with information that I need?

Best regards,

Dejan

[Here, you can see file that I'm trying to load](http://www.filedropper.com/graf1)

Comment: Can you specify a bit more in detail how you output is supposed to look like?

Comment: The structure of the graph should have fields that represent the vertices array of structures , each of which represents a single node . Each of these structures has fields id , type, name , edges and possibly some additional fields that are required due to the specific time ( previousVertexId , weightFromStart ) . Edges is a series of structures that represent one branch each of these structures has fields endVertexId , status and eventual some specific fields to search for ( eg . Weight ) . Status field indicates the state of the switch , which can be 1 or 0. In the start, status is 1

Comment: You should use a very simple example directly in your question (you can edit it). Let's say 3 nodes with the corresponding (arbitrary) lines of the txt-file. That write down what the output should look like.

Comment: I know, but its way to complicate to explain. Let's just say that I should load structure based on that file. I used fscanf, but it only reads one whole row as a string. How I have to change it that so it can read whole file and to contain fields id, type, name and so on..

Comment: [link](http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/matlab30project)

Here is detailed explained what I should do. Hope that you can understand. :)

Comment: [`fgetl`](mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) to read a line, then [`strsplit`](mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) to extract the different fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to **Stewie** answer is to use:

```
fgetl   to read each line
```

Then use

```
strread (or textscan) to split the string
```

Firstly using the `|` delimiter - then on the sub section(s) containing `,` do it a second time.